# How can i generate the combinations of numbers using ruby?

Tags: ruby, math, combinations

I need to generate the combinations of numbers using ruby. 
For Example :

arr = [1,2,3,4,5]

The constraint is, the combination number should include the number 5 and the length is minimum 3 or above. (i.e 125, 521, 1245 etc.. ). The above array elements (values 1 to 5) may occur one or two or more times in the combination number.

Comment: Yes, I mentioned above.. I have one array ( arr = [1,2,3,4,5] ). So, I need generate the combination of numbers like (125, 325,1245...etc.. this is my expected output). But, the number 5 is should contain in the combination number.

Comment: Right after I posted my comment I understood what you meant, so I deleted it. Interesting problem. I wonder what you need this for. And I wonder if someone comes up with an elegant answer too.

Comment: :-) nice!! Thanks mischa. If you like this question please vote up for me.

Comment: Consider improving your English so you can convey your ideas to people more effectively. I don't quite understand this sentence: "The values (1..5) may be occurred one more time in the result."

Comment: Who did this (Vote down)?. May i know the reason?.

Comment: Thanks tokland. Yes, i'll improve my communication. Please tell me the answer. If you have any doubt in my question please ask me.

Comment: @tokland had the correct answer until the question changed... In the previous version of the question 1 to 5 could occur only once, but now they occur twice or more?? Is `11115` a valid output?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
arr = arr * 5
out = []
3.upto(5) do |i|
  arr.combination(i) do |c|
    out << c if c.include? 5
  end
end
out = out.uniq.sort
puts out.inspect

# yields 2531 elements:
# [[1, 1, 1, 1, 5], [1, 1, 1, 2, 5], ... [2, 3, 5], ... [5, 5, 5, 5, 5]]
```

Comment: Excellent and well thought out answer. Here are a few suggestions. Instead of arr = arr * 5, try arr *= 5 and instead of out = out.uniq.sort try out.uniq!sort!

Answer (score 5):

[edit] Functional approach (requires Ruby 1.9):

```
xs = 3.upto(5).flat_map do |length|
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].repeated_permutation(length).select do |permutation|
    permutation.include?(5)
  end  
end
xs.size # 2531
```

Comment: This doesn't allow digits appearing more than once in the resulting arrays.

Comment: @Mladen: yeah, well, the question changed after my answer. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
combos = []              
for i in 3..arr.length
  combos.push(arr.repeated_combination(i).to_a)
end
combos.flatten(1).select{|c|c.include?(5)}
```

Here I'm creating a temporary container variable **combos** that will store every combination of 3 or more numbers in the array. I'm then filtering the array to only include combinations containing 5.